# Youtube API Upload - error in post 400 bad request

Tags: .net, api, youtube, httpwebrequest

i have some .net code which produces the following post (raw data coppied from fiddler, binary data truncated) however i am getting a 400 bad request every time i send the request

```
POST http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth ya29.AHES6ZTq4wOyYah1NRGrelvmg8icDsKwjkZuhN_IOdgDX75-
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=..apikey...
Slug: sample.AVI
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="dsjdwdjd3"
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Content-Length: 1980444
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Close

--dsjdwdjd3
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">testVideo1</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">this is a test video1</media:description>
    <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People</media:category>
    <media:keywords>test1</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
</entry>
--dsjdwdjd3
Content-Type: video/avi
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

RIFF�4�AVI LIST&....... truncated binary....
--dsjdwdjd3
```

here is the google documentation on the POST, however as far as i can see its exactily the same https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading.

My code behind is sending this as a httpwebrequest and that is as far as ive got.

EDIT: i do not believe it is a authentication or developer key issue as i have intentionally entered incorrect details and it comes back with a 401 invalid token or invalid developer key.

EDIT 2: complete response, pasted in raw format from fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 10 2012 14:42:33 (1334094153)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Up2iQ676IS9KRGmvmdbgBFGZLwLXHmnSv3cTUu-1TAHbuylsLncHOK0Q0MBSg22ZaGQ8aQ3JQps5bmAJ9xaYtYq1jNI_Q
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2012 10:11:10 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 15
Connection: close

Invalid Request
```

Comment: Can you also post the response? It contains a descriptive error message

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt, the only message it returns is invalid request

Comment: Can you still post the complete response?

Comment: I have added the complete response abocve in the question